# Finding Grobner basis using Buchberger's algorithm by Hand

Tags: algebraic-geometry, groebner-basis

[image: Question #2 Algebraic Geometry]

I could use some help with this question.  I have multiplied the first section by z and then subtracted the two polynomials from each other which has given me y=0, or x^2=z^2.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: I don't think you are evaluating correctly [degrevlex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order#Graded_reverse_lexicographic_order). I think that with that order you should have the monomials like this: $\langle yz+y^2-xz,\ y^2z-xz^2+x^2y\rangle$

Comment: Though here there is the interpretative issue of whether the author means "(the degree revers lexicographic) such that $x\succ y\succ z$" or "the degree-(reverse (lexicographic such that $x\succ y\succ z$))". I was claiming it to be the latter.